# Magento COD pincodes restriction

Tags: magento-1.6

magento shipping options restricted to pincodes.
I want to restrict my cod option to some pincodes.PLZ HELP

```
<?php
    //Edit pincodes here ...
    $def_pin_u = '110058,112233,114455,220034';
    $v_u = Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Progress::getShipping()->format();
    $l_u = strlen($v_u) - 1;
    for ($c_u = $l_u; $v_u[$c_u] != ','; $c_u--):
        $s_u = $c_u - 1;
    endfor;
    $s_u = $s_u - 1;
    for ($c2_u = $s_u; !is_numeric($v_u[$c2_u]); $c2_u--):
        $s_u = $c2_u - 1;
    endfor;
    for ($c3_u = $s_u; is_numeric($v_u[$c3_u]); $c3_u--):
        $s2_u = $c3_u;
    endfor;
    $se_u = $s_u-$s2_u + 1;
    $pin_u = substr($v_u, $s2_u, $se_u);
    $arr_pin_u = explode(',', $def_pin_u);
    $flg_u = 0;
    for ($c4_u = 0; $arr_pin_u[$c4_u]; $c4_u++):
        if ($pin_u == $arr_pin_u[$c4_u]):
            $flg_u = 1;
        endif;
    endfor;
?>
<?php if(($_code == 'cashondelivery' && $flg_u == 1) || ($_code != 'cashondelivery')): ?>
```

The errors I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Shipping_Model_Config' not found in /home/demo2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php on line 243
Fatal error: Call to a member function setStoreId() on a non-object in /home/demo2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php on line 109
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: i edited /www/app/design/frontend/em0006/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml

my code is below

Comment: <?php
//Edit pincodes here ...
$def_pin_u='110058,112233,114455,220034';

$v_u = Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Progress::getShipping()->format();
$l_u = strlen($v_u) - 1;
for($c_u=$l_u; $v_u[$c_u] != ','; $c_u--):
 $s_u = $c_u - 1;
endfor;
$s_u = $s_u - 1;
for($c2_u=$s_u; !is_numeric($v_u[$c2_u]); $c2_u--):
 $s_u = $c2_u - 1;
endfor;
for($c3_u=$s_u; is_numeric($v_u[$c3_u]); $c3_u--):
 $s2_u = $c3_u;
endfor;
$se_u=$s_u-$s2_u+1;
$pin_u = substr($v_u,$s2_u,$se_u);
$arr_pin_u=explode(',',$def_pin_u);
$flg_u=0;
for($c4_u=0;$arr_pin_u[$c4_u];$c4_u++):

Comment: if($pin_u == $arr_pin_u[$c4_u]): $flg_u = 1; endif;
endfor;
?>
    <?php if(($_code=='cashondelivery' && $flg_u==1) || ($_code!='cashondelivery')): ?>

Comment: the errors i get is
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Shipping_Model_Config' not found in /home/demo2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php on line 243
Fatal error: Call to a member function setStoreId() on a non-object in /home/demo2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php on line 109